# Interacting with one smart contract to another ? , Multiple smart contract interaction ? , One contract calls to another contract ? Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, smart-contract-wallets

Interacting with one smart contract to another ? , Multiple smart contract interaction ? , One contract calls to another contract ? in Solidity.

My questions  are:

1. How does a contract with each other ?
2. One contract interaction with another contract ?
3. Contract invocation without inheritance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So to solve this problem, Solidity not only provides for inheritance to invoke contracts in one another, It also provides a cool feature that helps devs/coders to invoke a contracts function from one contract to another without inheritance, Isn't that a neat feature.

Its solves the problem, e.g: A scenario where you want interact or invoke only one function of another contract, Why would you inherit and override all of its functions.

Solidity also gives the feature of invoking a Interfaces contract but the condition is that its implementer needs to implement that exact same function that was in its Interface.

Two Examples:

1. Simple contract invokes another contract
2. Interface is invoked in another contract

//import the contract you want to invoke first to do this in both examples

```
Example 1:

contract A
{
function someLikeableFunction()internal view returns(uint256){/*Does Something*/}
}

contract B{
function someDisLikeableFunction()internal returns(address){

A(/*Pass an Address of owner or caller*/).someLikeableFunction();

//you can store its value in a variable as well
}

}

Example 2:

contract Interface_A
{
function someLikeableFunction()external view returns(uint256);
}

contract A is Interface_A {

function someLikeableFunction()external override view returns(uint256){/*Does Something*/}

}

contract B{
function someDisLikeableFunction()internal returns(address){

Interface_A(/*Pass an Address of owner or caller*/).someLikeableFunction();

}

}
```